# Ionic Cordova Will Not Build, But Shows No Errors

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I just made a "new" ionic app, but I can't get cordova to build the APK. I put new in quotes because I created a new project and copied over the src from the previous project. Something went terribly wrong with the dependencies of a plugin install on that project, so I decided to start from a clean one.

I started the new project and installed all of the plugins that I needed. It seems to work as expected in the browser.

When I run `ionic cordova build android` this is the output:

```
PS D:\Ionic\PigsNBulls\PigsNBulls> ionic cordova build android
> ionic-app-scripts build --target cordova --platform android
[20:21:27]  ionic-app-scripts 3.2.0
[20:21:27]  build dev started ...
[20:21:27]  clean started ...
[20:21:27]  clean finished in 16 ms
[20:21:27]  copy started ...
[20:21:27]  deeplinks started ...
[20:21:27]  deeplinks finished in 111 ms
[20:21:27]  transpile started ...
[20:21:31]  transpile finished in 3.56 s
[20:21:31]  preprocess started ...
[20:21:31]  preprocess finished in 3 ms
[20:21:31]  webpack started ...
[20:21:31]  copy finished in 3.84 s
[20:21:36]  webpack finished in 5.03 s
[20:21:36]  sass started ...
[20:21:37]  sass finished in 1.24 s
[20:21:37]  postprocess started ...
[20:21:37]  postprocess finished in 12 ms
[20:21:37]  lint started ...
[20:21:37]  build dev finished in 10.14 s
[20:21:40]  lint finished in 3.12 s
> cordova build android
Android Studio project detected
(node:16624) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
(node:16624) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PS D:\Ionic\PigsNBulls\PigsNBulls>
```

It was working fine before this new project.

Comment: What plugins are you using? Have you tried to remove and readd your android platform and your plugins?

Comment: May I know your cordova version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have latest cordova 8.0.0 which causes above error. Please use below command:

```
npm install -g cordova@7.1.0
```